# blob read txt php

Tags: php, azure, blob

I've got a txt (plain text) file in my azure blob storage. Now I want to take it out and process the data. What I can do is download the file with the direct path to it, that works fine and gives back the file I've uploaded.

With a normal `.txt` file (not in blob but on website), it worked fine, but the blob file isn't giving me back what I need. The code shows how it worked with a non-blob file.

```
$file = $myData->ContentURI;
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($file));
echo $theData;
fclose($fh);
```

Now I want the same(or similar) code to read the blob txt. I'm sure the file does exist, because I can download it.

---

**EDIT:**

Managed to fix it myself, I changed the code mentioned above with the following code:

```
$file = $myData->ContentURI;
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either of the code:

Option 1: Read Stream

```
<?php
$blobUrl = "your blob's URL";
$fh = fopen($blobUrl, 'r');
$data=''; 
$size=102400;
while(!feof($fh)) 
    $data.=fread($fh,$size); 
fclose($fh); 
echo $data;
?>
```

Option 2: Read URL using file_get_contents

```
<?php
$blobUrl = "your blob's URL";
$theData = file_get_contents($blobUrl);
echo $theData;
?>
```

<del>Please ensure that the blob container containing the blob does not have `Private` ACL. It should either have "Blob" or "Container" ACL. You can read more about ACL here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179354.aspx. If you wish to keep the blob container private, then you must use a Shared Access Signature to create a temporary URL to read the blob from the blob container. You can read more about Shared Access Signature here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508996.aspx.</del>

Comment: The access is public (I can download the file). In the end I will set it to private and use a SAS, but for now I want it to work first.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Should've read the question carefully. I've updated the answer above. I just hacked this code by browsing through a number of PHP sites (Don't know anything about PHP to be honest), but it worked for me.